# Is it possible to create a vault that will open itself after a countdown (dead man's switch) on blockchain?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, cryptography

I know I can put an encrypted data and a timer in the contract, but what about the key? People can't know the key. It must be only used when the countdown ends, automatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best on chain scheduler?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102315/whats-the-best-on-chain-scheduler)

Comment: @Undead8, no. My scheduler involves decryption. I need the data in the "vault" (encrypted message) to be decrypted as soon as the timer expires, automatically.

Comment: Your question is too broad. As @Undead8 linked, there are a few ways of doing a countdown, but the blockchain only by itself cannot do it.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain the main problem here is about the decryption thing. I just want to know if it's possible to decrypt a message automatically on chain without revealing it's private key before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All inputs and output on a public blockchain must be public, so anyone coudl fast forward time and get the outcome key.

Some blockchains based on the trusted devices, like Intel SGX chips, might be a better choice, but they are still subject to attacks: https://scrt.network/